# notifyDataSetChanged() is canceling changing setColor in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, textcolor

as in topic, when I use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` text color in a cell which i have already changed is seting back to default value. I don't know why it happens im putting here me method for changing color:

```
for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
System.out. println("kolorujemy! "+ list.size() );
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) getViewByPosition(l,listView);
((TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_calosci)).setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

I would also add that this part of code is in loop in other thread because the vaules of the cells is updating every 30 seconds. Here is method getViewByPosition:

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
        final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount();

        if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
            return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
        } else {
            final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition+1;
            return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }
    }
```

getView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
if(convertView == null){
    listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
    convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_wlasnych_spolek, null);
    listViewHolder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_spolki);
    listViewHolder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_akt);
    listViewHolder.txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_kupna);
    listViewHolder.txtFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_calosci);
    convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
} else {
    listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

Comment: Please show your adapter code, or at least it's `getView(..,..,..)` method

Comment: @Jedil I updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this line
`return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);`
makes no sense, because with this call by hand you will internally always create and inflate new row for the list view but this view is never used within your `ListView`. See that you are always passing second parameter `convertView` null so internally this method will create new view but this view will be never used inside your `ListView`.
**Tip 1. Don't call `getView()` method yourself**

As you may know `ListView` stores in memory only as many rows/view as they are visible on the screen when you use `ViewHolder` pattern properly.

So for now you are setting color for every row that is visible and even those not visible that really not exist in `ListView`.

**Tip 2.**
Best way to color or change anything about any of your rows, is to do it just inside `getView()` method implementation depend on your adapter item state. Don't do it from outside because it looks like some kind of a hack or wrong architecture.